# Excel: user selection to larger range copy

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a user select a subset of a range and use a macro to select the much larger range to the clipboard for copying to a different workbook.

User Input:
`Range("A1:A5")`
Copied Range:
`Range("A1:DM5")`

Now how about:
User Input:
`Range("A1:C5")`
Copied Range:
`Range("A1:DM5")`

Thanks for any advice in advance.
klaus2

Comment: How do you determine the larger range?

Comment: It will always be Ax:DMx.
I guess if I can determine which row/s were selected then I can define the range for copying.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("A:DM"))

If Not rng Is Nothing Then 
    rng.Copy
    'etc etc
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have not been around for a few days.
I have come up with a solution that appears to give me what I want. I found the key through Googling.

```
Dim strSelection As String
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstCell As String
Dim lastCell As String

Sub Macro3()
  strSelection = Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                       RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
  firstRow = Range(strSelection).Row
  lastRow = Range(strSelection).Rows.Count + Range(strSelection).Row - 1
  firstCell = "A" & firstRow 'will always be "A" + firstRow
  lastCell = "I" & lastRow 'will always predetermined column + lastRow 
  Range(firstCell, lastCell).Select 'selects the range and ready for copying to another workbook
  MsgBox firstCell 'testing
  MsgBox lastCell 'testing
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Tim. I haven't tried it yet but will.